# ArgumentError in enum.rb:139: `assert_valid_value'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums, parameters, casting

My problem is to implement well working enum attribute for db-table.
Given is following class def:

```
class PlayerLicense < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team

  enum defaultDress: { black: 1, white: 2, :substitute => 3 }
  validates :defaultDress, 
            presence: true,
            inclusion: { in:  defaultDresses.keys}

  enum defaultPosition: { :defense => 1,  :forwarder => 2,  :center => 3,  :goalie => 4 }
  validates :defaultPosition,
            presence: true,
            inclusion: { in: defaultPositions.keys }

end
```

After browser submit (POST) is this  my rails server POST-log :

```
Started POST "/player_licenses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-11 19:12:34 -0400

Processing by PlayerLicensesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Gn4BmF4.......V1x50CYD0GknQJNQ==", "team_id"=>"7", "player_license"=>{"user_id"=>"6", "defaultDress"=>"2", "defaultPosition"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"assign this player to 'Smithfield guys' team"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)



ArgumentError ('2' is not a valid defaultDress):

activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/enum.rb:139:in `assert_valid_value'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute.rb:67:in `with_value_from_user'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:54:in `write_from_user'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:39:in `write_attribute'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:20:in `__temp__4656661657c6474427563737='
activemodel (5.1.4) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `public_send'
activemodel (5.1.4) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `_assign_attribute'
activemodel (5.1.4) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:40:in `block in _assign_attributes'
activemodel (5.1.4) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `each'
activemodel (5.1.4) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `_assign_attributes'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `_assign_attributes'
activemodel (5.1.4) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/core.rb:337:in `initialize'
```

In this example the Parameters coming from browser are so far so good, then enum.rb assert_valid_value is getting correct value (2) but wrong type (got: string, has to be: integer). That is the reason for ArgumentError in assert_valid_value.

In Rails console works everything OK, attribute/value assignments, validations, object.save/read. Check on db-level validates correct data record in DB-Table (after issuing object.save from rails console). What to hell is it (Params cast?), can somebody help,  some idea about the cause and solution  please? Thank you, Harry.

Comment: Just glancing at this, but I wonder if `{ in:  defaultDresses.keys}` should be `{ in:  defaultDresses.values}`.

Comment: 2 isn't a valid value for defaultDress because you're assigning the `defaultDresses.keys` which are black, white or substitute, perhaps you want to use the values?

Comment: thnx for response so far: [ all ] => actually i started with 'values', after trying 'keys' forgot to pull back to values, that's the reason why you see 'keys'.  in code. I agree first look: values. Surprisingly  'values' or 'keys' - there is no difference in results: on rails console it works well, from browser the same error.

Comment: Please post your form implementation

Comment: thnx for response so far: [ all ] => actually i started with 'values', after back and forth just forgot to pull back to 'values', that's the reason why you see 'keys'  in code. I agree 'values' are what we talk about. Surprisingly  'values' or 'keys' - there is no difference in results: on rails console both cases (keys/values) works well, from browser both cases the same error - pretty crazy. HTML is so far correct, I mean if you see the Params in server log, they are correct and clean, delivering values, the userSelect shows the key strings.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label 'dress', { :class => "control-label col-sm-2" } %>
    <%= f.select :defaultDress,
                 PlayerLicense.defaultDresses,
                 options = {},
                 html_options = {
                   :class => "col-sm-2",
                   :data => { :toggle => "tooltip", :placement => "top" },
                   :title => "select players banch color in this team"
                 }
    %>    
  </div>

Comment: form implementation: I mean as you can see in server log, the Param string (values) received by server are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with your form implementation. Instead of sending the enum key (the string), it is sending the enum value (the integer).

Instead of...

```
<%= f.select :defaultDress, PlayerLicense.defaultDresses ... %>
```

Use

```
<%= f.select :defaultDress, PlayerLicense.defaultDresses.keys ... %>
```

Comment: [Mark Merritt] => "you are right, to be more specific (PlayerLicense.defaultDresses vs. PlayerLicense.defaultDresses.keys) solved my problem. Thank you very much Mark. I would never think that way, because using helpers (f.select ...)  I assume the helper is doing the job in the right (verified) way - never mind -  thank you again, great job..

Comment: one more word: actually I see the real cause in the chain <browser-Params string => Data> conversion on server side. In the same way as rails console logic is doing ((object.defaultDress = "white") === (object.defaultDress = :white) === (object.defaultDress = 2), object.valid? === true, the same logics should work for the received Params on server (controller) side. Thnx Harry